# How can i set a conditional limit on Log_Entries which are counted?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

So I have a query inside my android ROOM DAO in which I receive the workout % completion, which is calculated as:

(Completed Sets/ Total Workout Sets) * 100

However, the problem I have is that the total workout sets is calculated by summing the total goal sets of each exercise for a specific workout.

The completed sets is calculated by summing the COUNT of each log entry. Therefore, it is possible for the workout percentage to succeed 100%.

Moreover, a user can enter many more sets than the target sets for a specific exercise. 
I need to be able to set a limit on the number of log entries which are being counted for each exercise.

(The log entry table has a junctionID which is unique for every exercise.)

How could I change this query to count only the first 3 logID's of each exercise (ignore anything surpassing this)?

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyrtM.png)

**Below is my current query:**

```
@Query("WITH entries AS ( SELECT COUNT(log_id) AS log_entry_count FROM log_entries_table AS l 
LEFT JOIN exercise_workout_junction_table AS e ON e.exercise_workout_id = l.junction_id 
WHERE l.date IN (:dates) AND e.workout_id = :workoutID), 
sets AS ( SELECT sum(set_number) AS set_sum FROM exercise_workout_goals_table AS eg 
LEFT JOIN exercise_workout_junction_table ej ON ej.exercise_workout_id = eg.junction_id 
WHERE ej.workout_id = :workoutID) SELECT ((SELECT log_entry_count FROM entries) *100/ 
(SELECT set_sum FROM sets))  AS workout_completion_pct" )

LiveData<String> getWorkoutCompletionPercentage(int workoutID, List<String> dates);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I've understood right what you want, but you can try query like that (maybe you'll get the main idea and fix it to your use-case):

```
// FIRST PART - MOST CHANGES HERE
// AS a result you should get form there all exercises ID and logs (up to 3)
WITH 
entries AS 
(SELECT l.junction_id, 
    CASE  
     WHEN count(log_id) > 3 THEN 3
     ELSE count(log_id)
    END log_entry_count FROM log_entries_table AS l 
INNER JOIN exercise_workout_junction_table AS e ON e.exercise_workout_id = l.junction_id 
WHERE l.date IN (:dates) AND e.workout_id = :workoutID
GROUP BY junction_id)


// SECOND PART - IS THE SAME
sets AS ( SELECT sum(set_number) AS set_sum FROM exercise_workout_goals_table AS eg 
LEFT JOIN exercise_workout_junction_table ej ON ej.exercise_workout_id = eg.junction_id WHERE ej.workout_id = :workoutID)


// THIRD PART - LITTLE CHANGES
// Change here - sum up all the counts of entries (they already cut to 3 maximal)
SELECT ((SELECT SUM(log_entry_count) FROM entries) * 100/ 
(SELECT set_sum FROM sets)) AS workout_completion_pct
```